# How to add settings for a scheduled job in Episerver

Tags: episerver

I need to add a checkbox that can be used to change the behaviour of a scheduled job in Episerver:

```
 public class ImportAlarms : ScheduledJobBase
    {
        /*I want the editor to set this*/
        public bool CheckBox { get; set; }

        public override string Execute()
        {
            OnStatusChanged("Starting execution of import alarms");

            var status = Import();

            return status;
        }

        private static string Import()
        {
            /*Do something with CheckBox value here*/

            var repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();

            var alarms = ImportAlarmsProvider.Import(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

            var createdCount = new AlarmRepository(repository).ImportAlarms(alarms.OrderBy(x => x.Date));

            return createdCount == -1 ? "No alarm container page set" : string.Format("Import completed, {0} pages imported", createdCount);
        }
    }
```

[image: I want one more checkbox like the Active checkbox that is there by default.]

I want one more checkbox like the **Active** checkbox that is there by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution to your problem, but check out this blog post: https://blog.mathiaskunto.com/2012/02/13/supplying-episerver-scheduled-jobs-with-parameters-through-admin-mode/

This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, this is what a was looking for. Too bad its such a hustle to implement :P

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution proposed by **andreasnico**, but a simpler approach could be to use **plugin settings** (although they're managed separate from the scheduled job in the UI).

Example of a plugin setting from https://www.epinova.no/en/blog/configuration-options-for-episerver-sites/:

```
 using EPiServer.PlugIn;

 [GuiPlugIn(Area = PlugInArea.None, DisplayName = "My Plugin Settings")]
 public class MyPluginSettings
 {
    private static MyPluginSettings _instance;

    [PlugInProperty(Description = "Some setting", AdminControl = typeof(CheckBox), AdminControlValue = "Checked")]   
    public bool SomeSetting { get; set; }

    public MyPluginSettings()
    {
       PlugInSettings.SettingsChanged += new EventHandler(PlugInSettings_SettingsChanged);
    }

    private static void PlugInSettings_SettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         _instance = null;
    }

    public static MyPluginSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new MyPluginSettings();
            }

            PlugInSettings.AutoPopulate(_instance);

            return _instance;
        }
    }
 }
```

You can retrieve the value in your scheduled job code like:

```
bool setting = MyPluginSettings.Instance.SomeSetting;
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, but this was not what a was looking for, however I can see alot of good usages with this and i actually implemented it for something else :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the biggest limitation when it comes to Episervers scheduled jobs... The lack of configuration options. One can't send any parameters to them and one can't select different times to run a job in a single day for example.

Your easiest option is setting the values you need in the job from appSettings.config or from a database.

Otherwise I would build a GuiPlugin. These normally show up above the Scheduled Jobs in Admin under Tools (if you chose to place it in that area). Your settings could be saved the way Ted describes, or you could save them in your database or use Episervers DDS (http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-Framework/7/Dynamic-Data-Store/Dynamic-Data-Store/).

You could also store the settings on StartPage or a SettingsPage or whatever you choose, however I'm not completely sure these would resolve when running the job scheduled instead of manually.